# Transforming Circuits—adding or subtracting currents?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

As shown in the attached image, given Circuit A, we convert the voltage sources to current sources and connect the resistors in parallel, as shown in Circuit B. However, what I don't understand is in going from Circuit B to Circuit C, the book says that $i_s = i_{s1} + i_{s2}$. But I am quite confused because since $i_{s1}$ and $i_{s2}$ are both going in the upwards direction (in Circuit B) and hence flowing in opposite directions, shouldn't we have $i_{s} = i_{s1} - i_{s2}$? [image: an]

(image credits to the Wiley brand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you can move $I_{S2}$ from the right side and place it on the left side in parallel with $I_{S1}$.

> That makes sense, but why would that work (i.e. not change the essence
>   of the circuit, so to speak)?

Since all the circuit elements are in parallel, you can move them around any way you want as long as they all remain in parallel, without changing the currents or voltages in the circuit. Each arrangement would be equivalent.

Take the simple case of a battery in parallel with a single resistor. The diagram shows the battery on the left and the resistor on the right. Would it make any difference if the diagram shows the resistor on the left and the battery on the right? Will that change the current through the resistor per Ohm's law?

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense, but why would that work (i.e. not change the essence of the circuit, so to speak)?

Comment: @singularity I have updated  my answer to respond to your follow up question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!